# How to get around 403 Forbidden error with R download.file

Tags: r, web-scraping, r-download.file

I am trying to download multiple files from a website. Im scraping the website to come up with the individual URLs, but when I put the URL's into download.file, I'm getting a 403 forbidden error.

It looks like theres a user validation step on the website, but adding a header doesnt help.

Any help getting around this is appreciated. here's what im trying with one sample URL and file :

````
headers = c(
  `user-agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.61 Safari/537.36'
)

download.file("https://gibsons.civicweb.net/filepro/document/125764/Regular%20Council%20-%2006%20Dec%202022%20-%20Minutes%20-%20Pdf.pdf", 
              "file", 
              mode="wb", 
              headers=headers)```
````

Comment: You might consider web scraping etiquette. Have you read the site's terms regarding using their data? https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/3q5qbk/what_is_good_scraping_etiquette/

Comment: It's behind Cloudflare protection and your client must be able to finish javascript-based check.  "*Checking if the site connection is secure. Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue. gibsons.civicweb.net needs to review the security of your connection before proceeding.*"

Comment: thank you John - I read the page and think Im using proper etiquette. and thank you @margusl - do you know if there's a way to wait and pass the check? or will I need to use rvest

Comment: The client must be able to evaluate javascript and set appropriate cookies, so you either need a fully functional browser  and control it through  rseleinum or  chromote. Or re-use your own browsing session. File content is delivered in POST response, so it makes sense to use httr instead of rvest if you decide to go that route. Might be useful - https://curlconverter.com/r/